# How can I copy a folder so that Windows Explorer takes into account file overlap before computing if there's enough storage space to copy the files?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-transfer, copy

As I was copying a few files between two external hard disks with Windows Explorer, my laptop running Windows 10 crashed. I restarted Windows, and I am  trying to reinitiate the file copy operation. However, this time I am getting the error message shown in the image below, because the destination drive had already  received most of the files I wanted to copy:

[image]

How can I copy a folder to another drive so that Windows Explorer takes into account file overlap before computing whether there is enough storage space to complete the file copy operation?

Comment: Using `/l /v /lfsm:<GB size>g` with `RoboCopy` may, but that would have to be tested to know for sure. [`/lfsm:<GB size>g`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy#retry-options) and [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy#remarks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy it using `robocopy` instead:

```
robocopy /e C:\Whatever E:\Whatever
```

This will automatically resume from wherever the previous copy process stopped.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a file-manager third-party alternative product,
if Explorer blocks such a copy.

See a plethora of choices with the article
[14 Alternative File Managers To Replace Windows 10 File Explorer](https://geekflare.com/windows-file-managers/).

Some products not on the list are
[FastCopy](https://fastcopy.jp/)
which is the fastest copier I know, and also
my personal favorite
[Altap Salamander](https://www.altap.cz/).

Comment: When downvoting an answer, please leave a comment with what's wrong with the answer